# How to keep the IntentService's attributes persistent?

Tags: android, android-alarms, intentservice

I'm building an application where an IntentService is periodically run using the AlarmManager:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent serviceIntent=new Intent(NewsListActivity.this, LatestNewsRetrService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingService=PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, serviceIntent, 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), REFRESH_INTERVAL, pendingService);
```

As you all know LatestNewsRetrService class is created and destroyed everytime the service has run; well, my problem is that I'd like to keep 2 objects used in this service like attribute, but that's impossible since everytime they are recreated.
I even tried to put those objects as extra into the service intent, but they won't update.
So, what's the best practice? Should I save those objects as attributes of the main Activity? What's the best thing to do to?

Answer (score 0):

> So, what's the best practice?

Store them in a file.